# Save Data from RecyclerView into SQLite DataBase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that gets image , text, url from json url in recyclerview and display the text and image in cardview. and when the user will click on the item it will open new webview activity and pass the url to this activity . everything work fine . but now i want to make a favorite list. when user click on button on the recyclerview item it will save this item data into the SQLite Database . I did everything as in Tutorials but it's not working

when i click on favbtn it's saying Failed . it means the data isn't saved in the database.

please any idea where is my mistake , I'm stuck on this for 3 days and can't find answer

here is my code

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Model> modelList;



    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Model> listData) {
        this.modelList = listData;
        this.mContext = context;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Model model = modelList.get(position);


        holder.title.setText(modelList.get(position).getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(modelList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button favBtn;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            favBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favBtn);
            favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatabaseHandler favDB = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Model model = modelList.get(position);
                    favDB.insertIntoTheDataBase(model.getTitle(),
                            model.getImage().trim(),model.getUrl().trim());

                }

            });

            itemView.setClickable(true);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Url = modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl();
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("url1", modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl());
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

DataBaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    Context context;


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Library.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_Demo = "Favorites";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE= "title";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE= "image";
    private static final String KEY_URL= "url";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_DEMO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Demo +
                    " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                    KEY_IMAGE +  " TEXT, " +
                    KEY_URL + " TEXT);";


            db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMO_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Demo);
        onCreate(db);


    }



    public void insertIntoTheDataBase(String title, String image, String url){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,  title);
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);

        values.put(KEY_URL, url);

       Long result = db.insert(TABLE_Demo , null, values);
       if (result == -1){
           Toast.makeText(context,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }else {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

    }
}
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    String title, image, url ;


    public Model() {
    }


    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private final String Data = "https://medicalibrary.net/wp-content/uploads/Allergy.json";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;



    public static HomeFragment newInstans() {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        return homeFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_acivity, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        httpGet();


        return view;
    }

    private void httpGet() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Data, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler (getContext());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Model model = new Model();
                        model.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        model.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        model.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("url"));

                        modelList.add(model);



                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(), modelList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


                        // context of your activity or fragment



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Tag", "onErrorResponse" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have something wrong with your inputs.  Try `Log.v("debug",model.getTitle() + "," +model.getImage().trim()+","+model.getUrl().trim());` and make sure that isn't it.

Comment: I'm getting this error
E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: ":"

Comment: What line of code is the error returning from?